# globals() binds to module where it was declared instead of where it is used

Tags: python

I am using a test framework that loads a module and then searches the scope of that module for `@test()` decorated function. What I am trying to do is to dynamically create those tests by dynamically creating those tagged variables.

It looks like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    globals()[f"Test_{i}"] = test()(Test)
```

For convenience I wrapped this up into reusable function and stuck it in another module:

```
def add_test(t, n=1):
    for i in range(n):
        globals()[f"{t.__name__}_{i}"] = test()(t)
```

However, when I import the `add_test()` function in a test module, and call it, no new variables are added to the test modules's global scope. If I move this function into the module where it is used, it works. It seems like `globals()` binds to the module scope rather than a true global scope. Is that analysis correct? How do I work around this?

Comment: You're surely better off storing these in a regular old `dict`. If you store it at the global scope in the module containing `add_test`, you can import the dict normally.

Comment: @BallpointBen I have no control over the testing framework. I must conform to what it expects. It loads the test module and searches its global scope for test decorated functions. So the test module must inject the tests into the test module's global scope. Therefor, `add_test` must non-locally affect the test module's global scope, which isn't possible. Currently, I dont see a way around having the test module call `globals()` (I dont like the idea of that being an argument to `add_test()`), and there is no other way to reference that scope, so there is no way to do what I want.

Comment: Perhaps I should generalize this question: "How to reference global scope of library user from library function"

Comment: After importing the dict, you can unpack it into the current module's globals

Comment: @BallpointBen I see what you are saying, you would have to inject the test variables into the global scope in the test module, but then the user would have to at some point call `globals()`, and I'd like to avoid that. I mean this to be reusable and I can't expect the users to know to do that (or even understand what `globals()` is or does, I mostly work with beginners). But I can always simply abandon this. The user could just be verbose (`Test1 = test()(Test); Test2 = test()(Test); ...`) unless they know the `globals()` *"trick"*.